Exit out of parent overflow hidden with position: relative div inside
I'm trying to implement tooltip in my HTML website.
The .element div is containing  tag and .tooltip. Now I want to display .tooltip while hovering .content element. The problem is that I want to place the tooltip above .content tag and to do so I need to set the .content position to relative but it breaks my fix for exiting out of overflow: hidden;
Any ideas how to fix it? JSFiddle


.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.parent {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: cyan;
  margin: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.element {
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  width: min-content;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: -45px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: pink;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.element p:hover+.tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="element">
      <p>Hover mee</p>
      <div class="tooltip">
        <h3>yeey</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>







.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.parent {
  max-height: 200px;
  background: cyan;
  margin: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.element {
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  width: min-content;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: -45px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: pink;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.element p:hover+.tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="element">
      <p>Hover mee</p>
      <div class="tooltip">
        <h3>yeey</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



